# Resizing SplitContainer makes controls invisible

Tags: c#, winforms

Why does the WinForms SplitContainer hide all the Buttons in a Panel (in the left Splitter) when I resize on of its panels? Do I have to write specific code for invalidation of the Panel?

Comment: It's not very clear.  Try posting some code that reproduces the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a solution. You can use [Anchor](http://www.dotnetperls.com/anchor) property of [SplitContainer](http://www.dotnetperls.com/splitcontainer) in winforms. Using which you can set the value of the anchor as you required.

EDIT:

Anchor property will make your control fixed to the winforms design. Even if you resize the control, all the controls that the major control is holding will also resize according to it.

Comment: what? it seems interesting , how anchors can help me with this ? resizing with spiltter?

Comment: You have not understand my question ! it makes the WNDPROC of Controls to be hidden !

Comment: splitter panels havenot any anchors!!

Comment: Sorry, you dint get it correctly. You can use the anchor property to what ever control you want in winforms. Use the anchor property for panel also.

Comment: add a panel to your form , dynamically at some buttons on that no resize that . tell me why ?